# Read two columns from Excel book to Dictionary<ID,string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have to read  two columns from Excel (ID and value) to Dictionary using C#. Can you please advise me how to achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have a sheet named "Country" with code and name in the first 2 columns
and also excel 2010.

```
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    static void Main()
    {
        string excl_connection_string = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\CountryCode.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""";

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Country$]";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(excl_connection_string);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Country Code = {0}, Name= {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the external free library EPPLUS: http://epplus.codeplex.com/ 
It's very fast and reliable (something which office automation or using oledb is NOT). 
Simply read in the via epplus, use the ToDataTable() method and read the datatable into your dictionary.